# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper.FileNamePattern.getDateTokenConverter()

Tags: java, log4j, logback, slf4j

I am using the following for my application:-

```
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
```

When I start the tomcat with my app. I am getting the following error:-

```
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper.FileNamePattern.getDateTokenConverter()Lch/qos/logback/core/rolling/helper/DateTokenConverter;
    at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.IntervalledTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicyBase.start(IntervalledTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicyBase.java:24)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndIntervalledTimeBasedFNATP.start(SizeAndIntervalledTimeBasedFNATP.java:21)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy.start(TimeBasedRollingPolicy.java:95)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA.end(NestedComplexPropertyIA.java:161)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:309)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:193)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:179)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:155)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:142)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:103)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:121)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:268)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:241)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:645)
    at org.springframework.core.SpringProperties.<clinit>(SpringProperties.java:51)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<clinit>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener.contextInitialized(IntrospectorCleanupListener.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4716)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
SLF4J: The requested version 1.7.16 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
```

When I search for **"ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper.FileNamePattern.getDateTokenConverter()"** in logback. I came to know as this method is not avail in logback newer version.

What is the workaround for it ?

Comment: I faced the issue when I updated the logback-classic from 1.2.11 to 1.2.13 but forgot to update logback-core to 1.2.13

Answer (score 2):

Seems that tomcat loaded more than one version of `logback`. Code referenced in stacktrace was removed back in 2011 in this [commit](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/commit/0fe93ab52a11545a7f88fd367d4777d14c733606). So you have to check libraries loaded by tomcat or downgrade your logback version to `1.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Logback docs will tell, add API and binding to Maven/Gradle. So you have to make two entries in POM. One for API of SLF4j, and one for binding to actual logger, which could be Log4J or Logback or java.util.Logger etc. It seems some other jar is already loading a log binding which is not compatible with what you are loading. So just remove the binding part from POM.